# Best way to redirect?

Tags: html, wordpress, redirect

I got a website made in Wordpress, and it's not finished yet but I want people to be able to only visit a certain link.

Let say my website is: [www.mywebsite.com](http://%20www.mywebsite.com), and the only section finished is [www.mywebsite.com/gallery](http://www.mywebsite.com/gallery).

Inside the gallery I have several links, that should work. (those links open new pages).

However, if people go to [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com), it should redirect them to [www.mywebsite.com/gallery](http://www.mywebsite.com/gallery).

I've seen several different redirect plugins, but I'm unsure what would be the best choice.

I want something simple that just works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML meta-tag:

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; URL=http://www.foobar.com/gallery">
```

PHP header function:

```
 header("location: /path/to/folder");
```

JavaScript:

```
 window.location.href = "http://www.foobar.com/gallery";
```

I suggest you to put a file (index.php) into your root folder and write the following in it:

```
<?php
 header("location: gallery/index.php");
?>
```

But if you have no PHP on your Server you can also use the method with HTML or JavaScript as well.

I hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since mwatzer answer seems correct to any website, I would strongly suggest to use a plugin or change your start page by setting your gallery page as home page, WordPress automatically removes scripts inside pages and entries, and if you change your template files, on the next template update they will be gone unless you create a child theme.

Check WordPress Codex here: [WordPress changing home page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page)

Or check this plugin: [Quick Page/Post Redirect Plugin](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/)

Comment: That's what I ended up using. Even though his answer is correct, I didn't want to mess around with the Wordpress code, so I just used a redirection plugin.

Comment: It is the correct answer for any website you are building, but the purpose of using a CMS is to focus on content creation, leaving programming skills to second place.